# Trying to get base64 representation of a file with cordova file plugin and ionic-native

Tags: cordova, ionic-native

I´am trying to get a base64 representation of a file with the cordova-file-plugin and ionic-native. But I´am getting a security_error.

The file is picked with the cordova-filechooser.

```
this.fileChooser.open().then((uri) => {
    const splitUri: Array<string> = uri.split('/');
    const file: string = splitUri[splitUri.length - 1];
    let path: string = uri.substring(0, uri.lastIndexOf("/"));
    path = path + '/';

    this.file.checkFile(path, file).then((exists: boolean) => {
        console.log('checkFile', exists);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('checkFile error', error);
    });

    this.file.readAsDataURL(path, file).then((result) => {
        console.log('success', result);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('read as data uri error', error);
    });
```

Thats what I get if I call the readAsDataURL method

> FileError {code: 2, message: "SECURITY_ERR"}

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is the path you are trying to access? It might be a system file that you do not have read or write permissions

Answer (score 0):

File api is incomplete (e.g. getFreeDiskSpace, writeFile) and docs is incomplete (e.g. readAstext)

Refer this URL

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/552